# change dateformat string in mysql table from number (milliseconds) to actual date

Tags: mysql

I have one tale users which have stored "date Of Birth"  in int(11) data type. I want to convert this in to Date type using `mysql`.

[image]

this is actual my database user table

is there any way to direact convert this `int type of datatype`  which is actually stored using `strtotime` function from PHP. So I am migrating this table in new database I want to change this field `datatype` to `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function is called FROM_UNIXTIME().

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

So, something like:

```sql
ALTER User Table ADD dateOfBirthAsDate DATETIME;
UPDATE User Set dateOfBirthAsDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(`DateBirth`);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use MAKETIME

```
MAKETIME( milliseconds /1000,milliseconds / (60*60),
          millimilliseconds / 60,
          seconds % 60 )
```

Also check [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(`date Of Birth`);
```